# Redis database creation and value committing

Tags: redis, save, persistence

I created a db using `select 10`
Then I set a key as `set x 20`
When I `get x` immediately the value seems to be `20`

But if I were to shutdown the client and wait for sometime (not sure how long), the same `get` operation gives me `(nil)`

How should I make this db and it's contents permanent?

*WARNING*: Redis super-n00b here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT does not create a database, it merely switches the connection to a given database.

Once you are connected again, you just have to SELECT 10 again to be able to retrieve your value. The default database is 0, so if you put your data in database 10, you need to SELECT 10 after each (re)connection to the instance.